# How To Update Table Relationships in TABULAR SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I've Imported multiple tables in my tabular model in SQL Server Analysis Services, after importing, I changed my tables structure and defined foreign keys. now my tabular model doesn't understand my changes and not showing me my relationships.

Does any body has any idea how to update my table relationships without recreating project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Opened my project in Data Tools AND Viewed it as Code. In View Code Mode, I Changed My Relationships And Added New Columns, Renamed My Columns And pretty much, Changed Everything.

It is more complicated than Design View but I think Its more powerful.

I was looking for this for a long long time, thought it may happen to you too, so I posted in here. :)